# How to create an installer for worker service of .NET Core using visual studio code

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I can add the Setup project to create an installer in Visual Studio 2019. But my requirement is to create an installer for worker service of .net core using visual studio code. 
I want to create an installer using visual studio code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use Service Control application to run the work service as a Windows Service. So you can just create a Powershell script that will run sc.exe and install the service.

Comment: I need the same thing - Setup project for .NET Core worker service. Any progress from your perspective? :)

Comment: Hi @TomasBlanárik I have created an electron app and combined worker service into it. And created a setup using Inno setup

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

Thanks
Rushi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28408092)

Comment: Exactly like I am looking for same solution and couldn't understand your  answer